# Rstudioの共分散構造分析のエラーが解消されません（lavaan関数）

Tags: r

**やろうとしていること**
Rstudioのlavaanパッケージを用いて共分散構造分析をしたいです（交差遅延効果モデル）
用いているデータは２時点のパネルデータです

**現在のコード**

```
model2009 <-'

#internal, institutionという2つの潜在変数でINFLU, COMPLEX, PARTY, ELECTION, CONGRESSという5つの観測変数を予測しています（変数名の後の1,2は２時点のうちどちらのデータかを表しています）
##モデルの識別のために係数の制約をかけています
internal1 =~1*INFLU1+a*COMPLEX1
institution1 =~ 1*PARTY1+b*ELECTION1+c*CONGRESS1
internal2 =~1*INFLU2+a*COMPLEX2
institution2 =~ 1*PARTY2+b*ELECTION2+c*CONGRESS2

#測定変数の誤差部分です
INFLU1~~INFLU1; COMPLEX1~~COMPLEX1; PARTY1~~PARTY1; ELECTION1~~ELECTION1; CONGRESS1~~CONGRESS1;
INFLU2~~INFLU2; COMPLEX2~~COMPLEX2; PARTY2~~PARTY2; ELECTION2~~ELECTION2; CONGRESS2~~CONGRESS2;

#構造方程式部分です
internal2~internal1+institution1;
institution2~internal1+institution1;

#潜在変数の誤差部分です
internal1~~institution1; internal2~~institution2; internal1~~internal1; institution1~~institution1; internal2~~internal2; institution2~~institution2
'

#以上のモデルをlavaan()関数を用いて予測しています
result2009 <- lavaan(model2009, panel.2009, ordered = c("PARTY1","ELECTION1", "CONGRESS1", "INFLU1", "COMPLEX1", "PARTY2","ELECTION2", "CONGRESS2", "INFLU2", "COMPLEX2"),
                     WLS.V = TRUE, sample.nobs=1107)
```

**直面している問題**
以上のモデルと関数をしようとするとRが次のようなエラーを吐きます

```
Gamma.g * tcrossprod(a1) でエラー:  適切な配列ではありません
```

検索などをかけたのですが、このエラーが何のエラーなのかよくわかりません。

**備考**
`taraceback()`関数で遡ってもみましたが、内容がよくわかりませんでした

```
traceback()
4: lav_test_satorra_bentler_trace_ABA(Gamma = Gamma, Delta = Delta, 
       WLS.V = WLS.V, E.inv = E.inv, ngroups = ngroups, nobs = lavsamplestats@nobs, 
       ntotal = lavsamplestats@ntotal, return.ugamma = return.ugamma, 
       Satterthwaite = Satterthwaite)
3: lav_test_satorra_bentler(lavobject = NULL, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats, 
       lavmodel = lavmodel, lavimplied = lavimplied, lavdata = lavdata, 
       lavoptions = lavoptions, TEST.unscaled = TEST[[1]], E.inv = attr(VCOV, 
           "E.inv"), Delta = attr(VCOV, "Delta"), WLS.V = attr(VCOV, 
           "WLS.V"), Gamma = attr(VCOV, "Gamma"), test = this.test, 
       mimic = lavoptions$mimic, method = "ABA", return.ugamma = FALSE)
2: lav_model_test(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable, 
       lavpta = lavpta, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats, lavimplied = lavimplied, 
       lavh1 = lavh1, lavoptions = lavoptions, x = x, VCOV = VCOV, 
       lavdata = lavdata, lavcache = lavcache, lavloglik = lavloglik)
1: lavaan(model2009, panel.2009, ordered = c("PARTY1", "ELECTION1", 
       "CONGRESS1", "INFLU1", "COMPLEX1", "PARTY2", "ELECTION2", 
       "CONGRESS2", "INFLU2", "COMPLEX2"), WLS.V = TRUE, sample.nobs = 1107)
```

Comment: 「Gamma.g * tcrossprod(a1) でエラー:  適切な配列ではありません 」とのエラーなのですから、tcrossprod関数の引数か、Gamma.gのいずれかに問題があるのだと思います。
この２つ(Gamma.gとa1)の値を質問に追加すると回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ただ、このgamm.g、tcrossprod といういずれの関数も手動では入れておらず、debug関数で処理の中身を見ても見つかりません。このような場合どうすれば問題の発生源を特定できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

原因はlavaan関数内の引数にありました。

#### 詳細

- 解決した理由は、lavaan（今回はsemですが）関数内のWLS.Vの引数を削除したためです。
- WLS.Vは使用するのがローデータではなく相関行列の場合にTRUEにする必要がありますが、最初の質問の時点ではローデータを用いていたにも関わらずTRUEにしていたため警告メッセージ、またはエラーが生じました。

#### 解決後のコード

```
model_cross2009 <-'
#lavaan()ではなくsem()を使っているため、測定変数や潜在変数の誤差分散は書く必要がありません
internal1 =~1*INFLU1+COMPLEX1;
institution1 =~ PARTY1+ELECTION1+CONGRESS1;
internal2 =~1*INFLU2+COMPLEX2;
institution2 =~ PARTY2+ELECTION2+CONGRESS2;

internal2 ~ internal1+institution1;
institution2 ~ internal1+institution1
'

result_cross2009 <- sem(model_cross2009, 
                        panel.2009,ordered = c("PARTY1", "ELECTION1", 
                                               "CONGRESS1", "INFLU1", 
                                               "COMPLEX1", 
                                               "PARTY2","ELECTION2", 
                                               "CONGRESS2", "INFLU2", 
                                               "COMPLEX2"))
```